# How To Detect a Terms exist or not

Tags: web-services, taxonomy

I am working on webservice which will validate terms , i need to check if given word is in terms or not, can any one help me how to do that in SP 2013?
and as i said i am using SP 2013 and Vs 2012, can anyone tell me how to debug webservice?

Answer (score 2):

in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.webservices.taxonomyclientservice_members.aspx

you can find all the methods that you need to work with the Taxonomy service by web service.

To check if a terms exist you can use, for example, the method GetKeywordTermsByGuids:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.webservices.taxonomyclientservice.getkeywordtermsbyguids.aspx